# How can I get access to EXT2, EX3 and EXT4 partitions on Windows 7?

Tags: windows, linux, ext4, ext3, ext2

I tried all programs recommended to mount Linux partitions like EXT2 or EXT3 or even EXT4 but no one can do well on Windows 7 32 bit.

I want to access read-write, is there a program that can do this?

Comment: which ones specifically have you tried? What issues do you face?

Comment: Check the related question: [How can I access a Linux partition from Windows?](http://superuser.com/questions/93664/how-can-i-access-a-linux-partition-from-windows)

Comment: I've tried the list of programs(explore2fs-1.08,Linux_Reader,ext2explore-2.2.71,ext2ifs-0.3,Ext2Fsd-0.51) ! neither one gives a good result !! I don't know what's wrong because while searching everyone says that's work correctly !,I should mention that is for my ext{2,3,4} USB external hard

Comment: If anyone happen to come across this question and needs a portable solution with read-only access (not mounting), check  [this answer at AskUbuntu.com](https://askubuntu.com/a/9935/770861).

Answer (score 7):

[Ext2Fsd](http://www.ext2fsd.com/) looks like what you are looking for.

> Ext2Fsd is a file system driver that allows accessing (both reading and writing) EXT2, EXT3 or EXT4 partitions from Windows. It works with Windows 2000, XP, Vista and Windows 7.
>
> Ext2Fsd has limited EXT4 support and by default it will load the filesystems in read-only mode, but you can force this if you really have to write on EXT4 partitions from Windows (this is not recommended). Using it, your EXT partitions will be displayed just like native NTFS or FAT partitions, being accessible from Windows Explorer.

Source: [Mount EXT4, EXT3 Or EXT2 Partitions In Windows 7 Or XP ~ Web Upd8: Ubuntu / Linux blog](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/08/access-ext4-ext3-or-ext2-partitions-in.html)

Comment: Sorry...but I tried it,it shows me the partitions and after creating a mount point I click on the partition as shown in MyCoumputer as a Drive it says:would you format the partition(yes/no) !! what's wrong?

Comment: Check out their [FAQ](http://www.ext2fsd.com/?page_id=7). It addresses your problem.

Comment: This page is no longer reachable

Answer (score -1):

Explore2fs does work :
http://www.chrysocome.net/explore2fs

cygwin with e2fsimage :
http://www.cygwin.com/

Comment: "Explore2fs is a GUI explorer tool for accessing ext2 and ext3 filesystems. It runs under all versions of Windows and can read almost any ext2 and ext3 filesystem." It is hence questionable whether it also works with ext4