# ext4 integration in windows 8 - access through explorer

Tags: windows-8, windows-explorer, filesystems, ext4, ext2

I know there are similar questions; however none I could find that addressed accessing ext4 through explorer, most others simply use a third party application.

However, my question is; is there a way to integrate, said third party application, in explorer, allowing one to access the hard drive as if it was natively supported, i.e. though my computer.

Otherwise, could someone suggest a working windows 8 third party application? ext2fsd and ext2explore don't seem to work for me.

Comment: [How can I get access to EXT2, EX3 and EXT4 partitions on Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/q/373806/241386)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ext2fsd and ext2explore seem to the most popular choices on the web for the job you want. However, bare in mind that they don't always leave the linux filesystem in a consistent state.

Anyway, these options do not work for you and i am not aware of a **reliable** application that can do what you want. The best thing to do is to use a linux live cd (ubuntu, puppy linux, damn small linux, etc) to boot your pc from it and then do anything on the ext4 partition like a boss.